# Change tinyMCE editor to allow marked content when pasting from Word

Tags: php, filters, tinymce

I'm a big supporter of how WordPress handles pasted text from Word, however for my client I need to change this.
My client is marking text within Word to use as a reminder (background color).
Does anyone know if there is a option/filter, without changing core-code, to make it possible that marked text from Word is not deleted?

I have tried the following but that didn't work. It did made some changes and added buttons like the code tells the editor to do but it doesn't keep the marked text.

```
function my_format_TinyMCE( $in ) {
$in['remove_linebreaks'] = false;
$in['gecko_spellcheck'] = false;
$in['keep_styles'] = true;
$in['accessibility_focus'] = true;
$in['tabfocus_elements'] = 'major-publishing-actions';
$in['media_strict'] = false;
$in['paste_remove_styles'] = false;
$in['paste_remove_spans'] = false;
$in['paste_strip_class_attributes'] = 'none';
$in['paste_text_use_dialog'] = true;
$in['wpeditimage_disable_captions'] = true;
$in['plugins'] = 'tabfocus,paste,media,fullscreen,wordpress,wpeditimage,wpgallery,wplink,wpdialogs,wpfullscreen';
$in['content_css'] = get_template_directory_uri() . "/editor-style.css";
$in['wpautop'] = true;
$in['apply_source_formatting'] = false;
$in['toolbar1'] = 'bold,italic,strikethrough,bullist,numlist,blockquote,hr,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,link,unlink,wp_more,spellchecker,wp_fullscreen,wp_adv ';
$in['toolbar2'] = 'formatselect,underline,alignjustify,forecolor,pastetext,removeformat,charmap,outdent,indent,undo,redo,wp_help ';
$in['toolbar3'] = '';
$in['toolbar4'] = '';
return $in;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_format_TinyMCE' );
```